# why doesn't my field get initialized to the value I gave it

Tags: java

I have following classes:

```
public abstract class AClass {

    public AClass() {
        aMethod();
    }

    abstract protected void aMethod();

}

public class SubClass extends AClass {

    private int x = 5;
    private static final int y = 6;

    @Override
    protected void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("x: " + x + " | y: " + y);
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass();
    }

}
```

Running Main prints the following: x: 0 | y: 6

Why does 0 get printed for x?

Comment: I guess your base class ctor is called before the private member x of your subclass is initialized. (My Java is a bit rusty tho)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason of the misbehaviour is a wrong *initialization sequence*:

1. `new SubClass()` executes `AClass` constructor
2. `AClass` constructor calls `aMethod()`
3. `aMethod()` shows `x` (which is `0` so far) and `y` which is `6` because of being *static*)
4. `SubClass` initialize its *non-static* fields, so `x` becomes `5`.

To avoid surprizes, *never* call *virtual* methods (esp. *overriden*) in constructors

Comment: But all methods are virtual in Java aren't they? however not all are overrideable.

Comment: @Andrew Spencer: yes Java methods are virtual by default (you can declare non-virtual `final` method however)

Comment: If you take a purely technical definition of virtualness, even `final` Java methods are virtual (they are late bound, ignoring optimizations). But I prefer your way of thinking about it - after all it's the "final" result that counts, i.e. inability to override.

Answer (score 4):

The static field is initialized as soon as the class is initialized (after loading). Now when you call
`new SubClass()` the following things happen.

> 1. Constructor of `SubClass` is called as the first statement of `SubClass` (implicitly)
> 2. Constructor of `SuperClass` is called. --> you are checking value of `x` here
> 3. Once `SuperClass` constructor's execution completes, then instance level fields of `SubClass` are initialized. So `x` will be initialized here.

Answer (score 3):

Initialization order. `aMethod()` is called before the line `private int x = 5`

Playing round with code examples like this is a great way to learn the order in which things are executed. Try adding a static and non-static initialization block too.

Answer (score 3):

The result is because the super class constructor is called before the members are initialized.

In your case the following sequence is executed:

- Call to constructor `SubClass`
- immediate call to constructor `AClass`
- call of method `aMethod()`
- initializing of members of `SubClass`

This is also the reason why you should not call any overrideable methods from a constructor as the called method may access the state of an object that is not fully initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int y = 6;
```

Value of y is 6 when the constructor calls *aMethod()*, because it is static and is initialized while class loading.

```
private int x = 5;
```

While this initialization is appended at the end of your constructor body. It means while *aMethod* is being executed, the variable x has still default value i.e 0.

Default constructor of *SubClass* would look like

```
SubClass() {
    super();
    //All instance initialization are performed here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you created an instance of the `Subclass` it invokes the constructor of its super class `AClass`, and at this point, `x` was not yet set that's why it gets the default value of 0.